# TextView: smaller letters (less wide)

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

Is it possible to make the letters in a `TextView` be less wide?
I have a fixed width for my `TextView`, it's `100dp`
There should be maximum 2 lines (it's two words, in every language)

In some languages that's perfect but in other languages it splits up the first word because it's to long. This fills up the two lines with 1 word that's split in two parts.

Is it possible to make sure that my letters are a bit smaller, so that the words fit in every language?

Comment: You could use a locale specific dimension resource for the text size, however, if you're following the recommendations and using sp for text sizes, then any language could wrap if the user increases their text size in settings.

Comment: You could also look for a font that has lower spacing between the letters.

Comment: Seems that my 'sp' size was a bit to high, solved it by putting it lower, but it looks pretty small right now. It's not perfect but it's as good as it gets, I guess...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually nothing native to auto resizing of the text in a text view... 
i hope the following answer suits your need..[refer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5535672/2681950)